# Is there any alternative to convolutional neural networks to classify Images?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

Deep learning is famous for classifying images into different categories. However, I am interested to use any other machine learning model which is capable of classifying the images. The images are about 2000 and are in png format. Does anybody know any machine learning model which can be applied in python to classify images other than Deep learning models.

Comment: you can use any ML algorithm like KNN, Logistic regression, SVM

Comment: great, and what about features?

Comment: you can either use pixels or derive features

Comment: There's currently not enough information to provide a meaningful answer. What's the task? How many classes? Do you have training data? If so how much?

Comment: @jodag I have some images(Landscapes), I am interested to train them using a machine learning model, except Convolution networks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to SVMs ([scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)). I can advise you to extract features from images first, with [SIFT](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.html) or [SURF](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) for example.

**EDIT**: SIFT and SURF are using the principle of convolution, but it exists plenty of other feature descriptors.